# Can a UWP-based DLL Project Export WinRT-type Classes?

Tags: c++, dll, windows-runtime, uwp

I've created a new project in Visual Studio 2015 based on the DLL (Universal Windows) Project type (c++/cx).  I've just added a new WinRT-type class to it and my client project has a reference to the DLL.  Compiles OK but I get an "unresolved external" during the linking stage for any method my client app tries to use.  As stated I have a reference to the project but I also import the .LIB file.  My question is: can a UWP DLL export WinRT-type classes or must the project be a Runtime Component?

Thanks,
-Glen

Comment: As far as I known, the  UWP DLL can export WinRT-type classes. Your error often means that some function has a declaration, but not a definition.

Comment: Except, the definition does exist.  In either case, I think the project type should be a WinRT component and not a UWP-aware DLL project.  The wizard doesn't set up a .winmd file for UWP DLL projects.